# How to use an indicator on SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Hello I am producing a report on SSRS 2008. I am using an indicator. In one of my text boxes i have a percentage. I want to link the indicator to that percentage so. For example: I want my percentage to be 90%. I want my indicator to turn to a green circle if it is 90% or above and want it to be a red X if it is 89% or below. How do I format an expression so that i can achieve my goal?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the data value of the field in your text box and is it in the same scope of the indicator?

Answer (score 0):

I would code something like the following for the Indicator Value:

= Iif ( ReportItems!MyPercentage.Value >= 0.9 , 1 , -1 )